# Potential maths rounding error with python voting system

Tags: python, database, math, rounding

I am making a quiz app. It has its backend controlled by python.
I have just typed this out as a thought experiment. I can probably type the code but im not able to figure out the maths behind this.

I want users to answer questions as usual, in various categories of questions. Also I want users to be able to vote on the value of each category.
Then further to be able to vote on the value of the subcategories.

There is an overall total and people score a percentage of that throughout all the question categories.

Max score for all categories and questions is 6000

```
 max_score = 6000
```

Each category has a percentage of that 6000
Users can vote on the categories value, up or down.
Each user has a power to change the percentage of a category by 0.00001% of 6000. This is like if everyone on the planet had a vote. but i cut the number down to a realistic number for the amount of visitors a major site could get.

```
user_vote = 0.00001/max_score

categories = {'General knowledge': '25%', 'Spacial Reasoning': '15%', 'IQ': '60%'}
```

so gen knowledge is worth 25% of 6000 points

if you up vote the category up. your percentage is added to the selected category

```
def vote_up():
    category_percentage += user_vote
    other_category1 -= user_vote / len(categories) -1 # -1 because one cat gets added to
    other_category2 -= user_vote / len(categories) -1 # will probably be more than 3 cats
    # more cats ....
```

So the value of the category changes but you still only score 10/10 per category

Then the same thing happens even smaller levels for sub cats like space questions, nature, sports.

```
gen_knowledge_sub_cats = {'history': '10%', 'sports': '10%', 'math': '55%', 'science': '25%'}
```

The issue is with removing the score from the categories that all now lose the value of the vote over the amount of categories that got down voted.
These sub categories get a split the percentage of their parent between them based on votes.

Am i not going to get some serious rounding errors after a while if alot of people vote. And the other_categories are at a certain number that leaves a remainder?

Im concerned it could turn out to be quite buggy. Im not quite good enough to figure out the maths behind this one.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the voting system you're describing, but it sounds like you might benefit from working with fractions (i.e., `fractions.Fraction` objects) instead of floating point numbers.

Comment: You could store the vote counts of the users as ints and calculate the percentages of the categories from these counts. Rounding errors won't accumulates this way.

Comment: Instead of working with percentages, work with tallies, and don't compute "the actual number" until you need to print it. Rounding and fractions shouldn't come into play until you need to derive a figure from your data.